# Asp-for tag helper in Material Design Lite with .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, material-design

I'm trying to get the `StatusId` of the selected item in my list.

I have a list of status created with Material Design Lite:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fix-height">
    <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="statusList" asp-for="Status" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="statusList" asp-for="StatusId">
    <i class="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    <label for="statusList" class="mdl-textfield__label">Status</label>
    <ul for="statusList" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        @foreach (var status in ViewBag.Status)
        {
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="@status.Id">@status.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I set the `StatusId` here:

```
<li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="@status.Id">@status.Name</li>
```

And I noticed that the `StatusId` go to this `input` when I select an item in the list:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="statusList" asp-for="StatusId">
```

[image]

I added `asp-for` in it but it is not working. The value in the `Controller` after the `submit` is ZERO.

The `asp-for="Status"` in the following input works perfeclty and the bind to the `Controller` occurs perfectly:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="statusList" asp-for="Status" readonly>
```

`Controller` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StatusId,CNPJ,Name,BusinessName,State,City,Street,District,CEP,Observation,Phone,Cellphone,Email,Status")] Company company)
{}
```

`CompanyStatus` model:

```
public class CompanyStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Company` model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    public string Observation { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cellphone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `status.Id` is not the same as `StatusId`. What does your model type look like?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the input type='hidden'? Does the bind occurs with hidden inputs?

Comment: @poke Just updated the question with more info.

Comment: Your input element’s value is `""` – Do you ever change that value on the client side? Otherwise, it will stay empty, and the empty value will be deserialized into the default value for `int` which is zero.

Comment: @poke When I select an item in the list, the value is filled up with the selected value and in the hidden input, the Id is set to the value as well.

Comment: @poke question updated with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the your action method on server  :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StatusId,CNPJ,Name,BusinessName,State,City,Street,District,CEP,Observation,Phone,Cellphone,Email,Status")] Company company)
{}
```

Here the Company Model expects fields of  `StatusId`, `Status` , and so on .

However , the `input` TagHelper on the server-side

```
<input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="statusList" asp-for="Status" readonly>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="statusList" asp-for="StatusId">
```

will be rendered into html tags as below when in browser :

```
<input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="statusList" readonly="" name="Status">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="statusList" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StatusId field is required." id="StatusId">
```

Note that when rendered in browser ,  the `name` attribute of the hidden `<input>` element is `statusList` instead of `statusId`.

The reason is that your `name` property of the `input` TagHelper on the server side overrides the `name` attribute generated attribute by `asp-for` property .

As a result , the payload you send to server will be:

```
Status=your-status-name&statusList=1&__RequestVerificationToken=xxx
```

Since the server doesn't care about a `statusList` field , it will simply ignore it .

I'm not sure how your Material Design Lite and client scripts binds value to the `input#statusId` when user select a `<ul>/<li>` . But if you want to send the request by form , you should change your viewcode from :

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="statusList" asp-for="StatusId">
```

to be :

```
<input type="hidden" value="" asp-for="StatusId">
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is with the 'name' property. But if I remove that property, the Material Design Lite binding doesn't happen.

Comment: @perozzo Is it possible to change your `ul[for='statusList']` (will be token by Material Design Lite)  to  `ul[for='statusId']`  , and set the `input[name='statusId']` at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I did that and it worked like a charm. I was thinking if it can be a problem in the future because of the same name of all elements.